# Telnet session with batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, telnet

My goal is to retrieve some info from my adsl modem within a telnet session. I do not want to use cmd. I want to create a batch file to automize all the process. The telnet session from windows cmd is the following:

```
Password: ***********
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2006 ZTE CORPORATION.
ZTE> show lan
DHCP setting:
DHCP Mode      = None
TCP/IP Setup:
IP Address     = 192.168.1.1
IP Subnet Mask = 255.255.255.0
Rip Direction  = None
Version        = Rip-2B
Multicast      = IGMP-v2
ZTE> exit
```

The strings `***********`, `show lan` and `exit` are user inputs. All the remaining is telnet output.

Comment: see: [Can the Windows telnet client be scripted?][1]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/41919/can-the-windows-telnet-client-be-scripted

Comment: I'm working with java, c++  and matlab together and I don't want to expand with other language, it will be terrible to manage. There is also a jar lib for java from apache but it doesn't work good due to input/output stream coordination bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to consider using [Telnet Scripting Tool](http://ss64.net/tst10.zip) third-party with it's `/r:` switch that accepts input commands file as an argument.

Comment: After a bit of hesitation in using the telnet library of python, in the end I gave up. Anyway I'll consider your answer as a valid solution to the problem.

Comment: I am using a 64 bit machine, is that why this tool does not work for me? I am getting some error. Possible reasons ?